# Layout not visible in Full Screen Activity in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android

I intend to create a splash screen in my *Xamarin Android* project.

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" android:background="#11aaff">
  <ImageView
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/splash" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The following code:

```
[Activity(Label = "My Xamarin App", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen",
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
  public class SplashScreenActivity : Activity
  {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
      SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen);
      // Create your application here
      //var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
      //StartActivity(intent);
      //Finish();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
      base.OnStart();
      // Create your application here
      var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
      StartActivity(intent);
    }
  }
```

After starting the app, I get a *white screen* (note the theme) and my second activity (`MainActivity`) shows up after a few seconds.

If I remove the `StartActivity` and show the splash screen only, it shows the white screen for about 1-2 seconds, then the image and the blue bacground appear (as expected) - obviously the second activity is not started.

What should I do to make the layout appear immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom Theme, instead of a custom layout.

Just a note, for this solution to work you must add the following Nugget Packages to the project:
**Xamarin.Android.Support.v4** and **Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat**
As stated in the reference link bellow.

I had to do that a while back and used this link as reference:
[Creating a Splash Screen](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/creating_a_splash_screen/)

Basically, you create a .xml file in your drawable folder with something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <color android:color="@color/splash_background"/><!-- Your BG color here -->
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/splash"<!-- your splash screen image here -->
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="center"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then you edit the styles.xml file (by default in Resources/values), and add:

```
<style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item><!-- here you should put the name of the file you just created in the drawable folder -->
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>  
  <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Finally your Splash Screen should extend *AppCompatActivity* instead of *Activity* and the Theme should be your custom, like this:

```
[Activity(Label = "My Xamarin App", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash",
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
  public class SplashScreenActivity : AppCompatActivity
```

I Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I really should've used that official Xamarin approach in the first place :)